# NOT able to do MAX , COUNT into a single Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've been trying to get the maximum number from a set of different values.
suppose,
i have table with values,

```
id    val
A     1
A     2
A     3
B     4
B     5
C     6
```

so i want to get the maximum number of id and first i did get the count and tried to get maximum
my sql query is,

```
SELECT MAX (ID_COUNT) id_count 
FROM (SELECT id,COUNT(id) ID_COUNT
FROM tab1
GROUP BY id)
```

I want an ouput 3 since A is repeated 3 times and is the maximum.

it was supposed to work. but now im getting an error saying derived table value should have an alias. but i did give an alias.
what should i do?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an alias for the sub select

```
SELECT MAX (ID_COUNT) id_count 
FROM (SELECT id,COUNT(id) ID_COUNT
FROM tab1
GROUP BY id) tab2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT id,COUNT(id) ID_COUNT
FROM tab1
GROUP BY id
order by ID_COUNT desc
limit 1
```